# How to get mouse inputs from raw data?

Tags: python, input

Hello I am trying to develop a Linux game python for coding so anything in python would work. The game requires two mouse inputs (movement and mouse clicks). I want to get the info from the files in /dev/input but a more convenient way would help.

I've already got code to get the input file I want (/dev/input/event13 and /dev/input/event14) that works great. I've tried a lot of things but have only been able to get left click right click and a broken middle click which also triggers right click.
Thanks!

The code for the thing that can get the input file is this:

```
import evdev
def dev1():
    devices = [evdev.InputDevice(path) for path in evdev.list_devices()]
    for device in devices:
        print(device.path, device.name)
    try:
        device1 = float(input('Type number of Mouse1. Not a number to update. '))
    except ValueError:
        dev1()
def dev2():
    devices = [evdev.InputDevice(path) for path in evdev.list_devices()]
    for device in devices:
        print(device.path, device.name)
    try:
        device2 = float(input('Type number of Mouse2. Not a number to update. '))
    except ValueError:
        dev2()
dev1()
dev2()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have any code so for this that is why I'm asking. Unless you mean the code that finds the input file for the mice, that doesn't matter though as it works and only gives and output of the input files and doesn't actually help this problem. I'll post it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The `pynput` module has a callback-based interface that let's you monitor mouse events such as movement and and clicks.

Check it out

Comment: Can you have two mice in that though?

Comment: I need separate inputs so I don't think it would work.